# i don't know why there's nothing on my facebook after posting job

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

i'm making a test c# winform program for posting onto the facebook with sdk.
my codes are below; i guess it worked successfully and i got final result such as {{"id":"110367383104533_110569899750948"}}
but there was nothing newly posted when i entered my facebook.
there's no error. what's wrong with this situation?

```
        string sAppID = "<MyAppID>";
        string sAppSecret = "<MyAppSecretCode>";
        string sAccessToken = String.Empty;
        string sPageID = String.Empty;

        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("/oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = sAppID,
            client_secret = sAppSecret,
            grant_type = "client_credentials", 
            scope = "manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_stream" 
        });
        sAccessToken = result.access_token;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sAccessToken))
        {
            fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(sAccessToken);
            fb.AccessToken = sAccessToken;
            fb.AppId = sAppID;
            fb.AppSecret = sAppSecret;

            dynamic fbAccounts = fb.Get($"/{sAppID}/accounts");

            foreach (dynamic account in fbAccounts.data)
            {
                sPageID = account.id;
                sAccessToken = account.access_token;
                break;
            } //foreach

            fb = new FacebookClient(sAccessToken);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = tbxMessage.Text;
            dynamic dResult = fb.Post($"/{sPageID}/feed", parameters);
            MessageBox.Show(dResult.id);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("failed to get access token");
            return;
        } // else
```

Comment: When you login to Facebook via browser, you need email\password. So how this email is related to `client_id`? Is it for the same account? In addition, I see you do `foreach` for items store the id and token but use only the first. How do you know you are using the right one? print `account.id` to verify.

Comment: about the reason why i used the first one. there was no matched id though there is only one data. so i had to use that access token to do this thing. plus, i must do this posting job without web-login window. i'm not sure of this facebook sdk. but twitter sdk works correct.